# How the HTTP methods are implemented in Spring RESTful (HEAD, OPTIONS, CONNECT, TRACE)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

I would like to find out what an example implementation of HTTP methods (**HEAD, OPTIONS, CONNECT, TRACE**) looks like in Spring Framwerok.

Because I can't find much information on what it would look like other than the standard methods like GET, POST, PUT....

example of GET:

```
@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
Employee one(@PathVariable Long id) {
    
  return repository.findById(id)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id))
}
```

Comment: see also https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/15335

Answer (score 0):

Annotation that you've mentioned (GetMapping) is a shorthand for *@RequestMapping* annotation. You can check source code for *@RequestMapping* annotation for yourself:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @interface GetMapping {
```

It works because spring parses annotation inside other annotations. Check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) another example of Spring annotations processing with @SpringBootApplication.

Regarding http methods: Spring MVC [documentations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) says that there are next shorthand annotations:

- @GetMapping
- @PostMapping
- @PutMapping
- @DeleteMapping
- @PatchMapping

All other available methods should be declared using @RequestMapping annotation. It accept *RequestMethod* enum as parameter, check this [enum](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/46bd6add15bb41163445e375908df33af2831b95/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMethod.java#L39) for available options. Notice that TRACE and OPTIONS methods processing should be enabled explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

HEAD Method: The HEAD method is similar to the GET method in that it delivers only the response headers rather than the actual content. To handle HEAD requests in Spring Framework, use the @RequestMapping annotation with the method parameter set to RequestMethod.HEAD.

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> headEmployeeById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    Employee employee = repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));
    headers.add("employeeId", String.valueOf(employee.getId()));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

OPTIONS Method: The OPTIONS method is used to get a list of HTTP methods that a site supports. You may use the @RequestMapping annotation in Spring Framework with the method argument set to RequestMethod. OPTIONS is used to process OPTIONS requests.

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> optionsEmployees() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Allow", "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The CONNECT method is used to connect to a resource across a network. You may use the @RequestMapping annotation in Spring Framework with the method argument set to RequestMethod. CONNECT is in charge of handling CONNECT requests.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/connect", method = RequestMethod.CONNECT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> connect() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Connection", "keep-alive");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The TRACE technique is used to obtain diagnostic information about a request/response cycle. You may use the @RequestMapping annotation in Spring Framework with the method argument set to RequestMethod. TRACE will handle TRACE queries.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/trace", method = RequestMethod.TRACE)
public ResponseEntity<String> trace(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "message/http");
    String requestString = RequestUtil.convertToString(request);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(requestString, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement controllers for any of methods in Spring you could use @RequestMapping annotation

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS, value="/employees")
```

See this article for more information
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping